# How can I use VBA code to copy/paste to another workbook given a location?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, paste

I have been working for weeks on this, perhaps it is helpful if I include a picture depicting exactly what I am trying to do. I want to create a macro to loop through and paste these values to specific locations in another workbook. The locations change depending on the day, so I need to do it this way. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Use the values in columns F, G, and H, together with `Cells`, to refer to the destination range.

Comment: Please share the code you got so we can build on it.